# Language selection using images in PHP

Tags: php

I have found an open source PHP script that uses a select menu to choose the language.

In the code session makes use of a loop to fill in the select menu, as above...

```
$la = 0;
foreach($trans['languages'] as $short=>$langname)  {
$params['LANGSEL'][$la]['LANG_SHORT'] = $short;
$params['LANGSEL'][$la]['LANG_LONG'] = $langname;
$la++;
}
```

In the php template creates the select menu like that...

```
<td><select class="select" name="lang"><#FOR LANGSEL#>
<option value="<#LANG_SHORT#>"><#LANG_LONG#></option>
<#/FOR LANGSEL#></select></td>
```

So this code works fine but i find it kinda ugly so i am trying to make an image input instead
So i thought something like that would work..

```
<input type="image" name="lang" value="http://localhost/index.php?lang=en" src="        <#IMAGES_DIRECTORY#>/english.png"></td>
<input type="image" name="lang" value="http://localhost/index.php?lang=it" src="   <#IMAGES_DIRECTORY#>/italian.png"></td>
```

But nothing changes, the page always shows up in italian that is the default language..
Thanks in advance from a newbie that is struggling to learn some html and php.

Comment: How are you actually *setting* the language inside index.php? *That's* the interesting part.

Comment: Also consider utilizing `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` as base setting.

Comment: An input element of type "image" behaves just like a submit button, except for the click-position, which is sent as additional information. You could use a separate link for each flag, which contains the flag as an img-element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of your **name** field should be `<#LANG_SHORT#>`. You don't say what it looks like *after* being processed but I'm pretty sure it's something like `en` or `it`. However, you provide a URL. You also prepend several white spaces to the image's URL.

This will probably work:

```
<input type="image" name="lang" value="<#LANG_SHORT#>" src="<#IMAGES_DIRECTORY#>/english.png"></td>
```

Remember to test it in Internet Explorer. It's traditionally had several problem with `<input type="image">` elements.

Comment: Thank you all guys for bothering answering to me. I am sure all of the solutions you suggested are correct. But Alvaro's was the simpliest one and would do the trick. So just writing <td><input type="image" name="lang" value="<#LANG_SHORT#>en" src="<#IMAGES_DIRECTORY#>/english.png"></td> worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have *two* images with different `name`s, whereas you need to only have *one* form element, called `name`, whose value is the correct `<#LANG_SHORT#>` string. In this regard, `select` and `radio` form elements are perfectly suited to the job, whereas `input`s are not.

It also seems unlikely to me that the form element *really* has a value of `http://localhost/index.php?lang=en`. Isn't that merely the URL that results from changing the language? It seems more likely that the proper value for your form fields is just `en`/`it`.

Ultimately, I reckon you're going to need a hidden form field, and some Javascript on your `image`s to set that field's value when required. And be aware that the usability/accessibility of your site just went from [potentially] high to [definitely] very low.